# Why this iteration works forever

Tags: javascript, iteration

Why this code run infinite time.
I don't understand what happened.

```js
(function(){
    console.log("Start")

    function add(){
        s.delete(add); //When I delete this line, everything works fine.
        s.add(add);
        console.count("run")
    }

    const s = new Set([
        add
    ]);

    s.forEach(value => {
        value()
    });
    
    console.log("Finish")
})()
```

This is an overview code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this is in the spec for [`Set.prototype.forEach`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set.prototype.foreach):

> Each value is normally visited only once. **However, a value will be
> revisited if it is deleted after it has been visited and then re-added
> before the forEach call completes.** Values that are deleted after the
> call to forEach begins and before being visited are not visited unless
> the value is added again before the forEach call completes. New values
> added after the call to forEach begins are visited.

Since it's a function that you keep adding and running it keeps doing that, deleting and adding it back again. So therefore you create an infinite loop.